# Scala: Calling method/accessing value on argument wildcard

Tags: scala, wildcard

How do I call a method on or access a value of an argument wildcard? E.g. in this example I want to find the max "rev" value of all F objects.

```
scala> case class F(rev:Long)
defined class F

scala> List(F(1),F(2),F(3))
res3: List[F] = List(F(1), F(2), F(3))

scala> res3.foldLeft(0L){math.max(_,_.rev)}
<console>:11: error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 2
              res3.foldLeft(0L){math.max(_,_.rev)}
                                    ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use wildcards here and need to give names to the arguments:

```
res3.foldLeft(0L){(x,y) => math.max(x,y.rev)}
```

Note that it would be the same if you had a function `foo` taking 1 argument instead of `math.max`: `foo(_.rev)` is the same as `foo(x => x.rev)` and not `x => foo(x.rev)`.

The problem is the scope of wildcards. `math.max(_,_.rev)` expands to (I think) `x => math.max(x, y => y.rev)`. Since this function only has one parameter, you get this error.

Comment: But would does this not work? According to the Scala spec multiple wildcards are replaced by the first argument, second argument, third argument and so on... The above code would for example work on a List[Int] with `math.max(_,_)`